# Java constructor: creating an object, short parameters are interpreted as int

Tags: java, constructor, integer, short

I'm writing a little sorting program in Java designed to grab a "student" object and determine what its name, career and classroom is dependent on parameters and attributes. A problem turns up, however, when I try to create the first object.
Thus far, everything looks like this:

```
public class Student {
    private String name, classroom;
    /**
     * The career code is as follows, and I quote:
     * 0 - Computer Science
     * 1 - Mathematics
     * 2 - Physics
     * 3 - Biology
     */
    private short career, idNumber;

    public Student (String name, short career, short idNumber){
        this.name = name;
        this.classroom = "none";
        this.career = career;
        this.idNumber  = idNumber;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        Student Andreiy = new Student("Andreiy",0,0);
    }
}
```

The error turns up on the object creation line, as for some reason it insist on interpreting 0,0 as integers when the constructor calls for shorts, leading to a mismatch problem.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post the exception or error details?

Comment: cast the integer to short: `new Student("Andreiy", (short)0, (short)0);` or write an 's' after your short number: `new Student("Andreiy", 0s, 0s);`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/477750/primitive-type-short-casting-in-java?rq=1 related

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2720821/55284 should explain what you need to know.

Comment: @StefanFandler - The `s` suffix doesn't work in Java.

Answer (score 2):

One way is to tell the compiler that the value is a `short` using a cast:

```
Student Andreiy = new Student("Andreiy",(short)0,(short)0);
```

Alternatively, redefine the `Student` class to accept `int` instead of `short`. (For the career code, I'd suggest using an `enum`.)

Answer (score 0):

You should convert Integer to short. Integer to short conversion requires narrowing so explicit cast is required. You should use integers in java as long as you have memory constraints.

```
public Student (String name, Career career, int idNumber)

//Enumeration for Career so no additional checks are required.
 enum Career
 {
     Computer_Science(0),Mathematics(1),Physics(2),Biology(3);
     private Career(int code)
     {
         this.code = code;
     }
     int code ;

     public int getCode()
     {
         return code;
     }

 }
```

And then you can do something like below

```
new Student("Andreiy", Career.Computer_Science, 0);
```