# Why I can't declare Enum Type with short constructor argument?

Tags: java, constructor, enums

First off, sorry for my english...

I'm doing a Enum type but I can't do, because I'm using  `tipo(String nombre, short valor)`

Why must I use `tipo(String nombre, int valor)`? Using **int** instead of **short**?

```
public enum Tipo {

    // The constructor (String, int) is undefined
    DAT ("DAT", -2);



    private String nombre;
    private short valor;

    tipo(String nombre, short valor){
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.valor = valor;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public short getValor() {
        return valor;
    }

    public void setValor(short valor) {
        this.valor = valor;
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java - short and casting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2720738/java-short-and-casting)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try `DAT ("DAT", (short)-2);`

You are passing an `int` to a constructor that takes a `short`. Java doesn't auto-cast from `int` to `short` because of the potential loss of data.

A very good explanation of this can be found [here - primitive type short casting in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477750/primitive-type-short-casting-in-java)

Comment: But for literals this is only true for method parameters. E.g. variable initialization works fine.

Comment: I have finished reading it. And I completely understand. as summarized say:

Operates by default Java int. If you lose data operating with short, java forces you to do it by hand. Thanks!!

Answer (score 5):

There are two changes you need to make to the above:

1) Fix typo with your field 'Valor' to be lower case

```
private short valor;
```

2) Cast the int to a short:

```
DAT ("DAT", (short)-2);
```

Additionally, you should also rename your enum type to be 'Tipo' which is the recommended naming format for enums.

Answer (score 1):

By default a primitive number will be treated as an integer, and going from an integer to a short requires a cast. The compiler wont perform this type casting automatically - this is because going from a larger (an int) to a smaller (a short) introduces the risk of losing data (by truncating the number) and so the compiler forces you to cast it.

So you have two choices:

```
DAT("DAT", (short)-1);
```

or

```
private short valor;
Tipo(String nombre, int valor){
    this.valor= (short)valor;
```