# Scala `+` functor defined on Int maps from Short to Int?

Tags: scala, type-deduction

I'm writing a custom tree/graph container for smaller serialisation, and i'm getting a compiler error, apparently adding something to a short produces an Int.

```
def traverse(tree : Tree, level : Short = 0, pos : Short = 0) {
  buf(level) += tree
  var pos : Short = -1
  tree.getChildrenAsList.iterator().foreach { z=>
    pos += 1
    traverse(z, level + 1 ,pos)
  }
}

[error] /Users/hassan/code/scala/avro/src/main/scala/edu/hsyed/nlp/MyTree.scala:33: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : Int
[error]  required: Short
[error]         traverse(z, level + 1 ,pos)
```

I'm having to do this, which seems a bit unusual because of scala's impressive type deduction :

```
def traverse(tree : Tree, level : Short = 0, pos : Short = 0) {
      buf(level) += tree
      var pos : Short = -1
      tree.getChildrenAsList.iterator().foreach { z=>
        pos = (pos + 1).toShort
        traverse(z, (level + 1).toShort ,pos)
      }
    }
```

**edit**

Aah the question is, how do I get around this ?

Comment: This look suspiciously like a consequence of [Java's primitive numerical shenanigans](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2720738/java-short-and-casting).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create additional method for sum of `Short`.

There is already such methods in `scala` in `Numeric` type class:

```
import scala.math.Numeric

val ns = implicitly[Numeric[Short]]
val s = 1: Short

ns.plus(s, s)
// Short = 2

ns.times(3, 2)
// Short = 6
```

In case you can abstract over `Short` type you could use `+` method from `Numeric.Implicits` like this:

```
import Numeric.Implicits._
def traverse[T: Numeric](tree: Tree[T], level: T, pos: T) {
  val one = implicitly[Numeric[T]].one

  buf(level) += tree
  var pos: T = -one
  tree.getChildrenAsList.iterator().foreach { z =>
    pos += one
    traverse(z, level + one, pos)
  }
}
```

You could also use `|+|` from `scalaz` as replacement for `+`:

```
import scalaz._, Scalaz._

s |+| s
// Short = 2
```

Comment: Very high quality answer, the second section of code especially. The first part alone would not have sufficed in getting the intention/use-case of the Numeric class across. It is also a good bridge for why scalaz, and further why monoids since you showed the `.one` method. At some point I need to understand what `implicitly` is meant for :D