# "possible loss of precision" is Java going crazy or I'm missing something?

Tags: java, casting, precision

I'm getting a "loss of precision" error when there should be none, AFAIK.

this is an instance variable:

```
byte move=0;
```

this happens in a method of this class:

```
this.move=(this.move<<4)|(byte)(Guy.moven.indexOf("left")&0xF);
```

move is a byte, move is still a byte, and the rest is being cast to a byte.

I get this error:

```
[javac] /Users/looris/Sviluppo/dumdedum/client/src/net/looris/android/toutry/Guy.java:245: possible loss of precision
[javac] found   : int
[javac] required: byte
[javac]             this.move=(this.move<<4)|(byte)(Guy.moven.indexOf("left")&0xF);
[javac]                                         ^
```

I've tried many variations but I still get the same error.

I'm now clueless.

Comment: What if move is 128? When you shift it by 4 bits, that will cause a loss of precision. Is "byte << N" defined to return another byte, or an int?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually all logic operatos (& | ^) return an **int**, regardless of their operands. You have to cast the final result of x|y as well.

Comment: oh! Thanks! (to leonbloy and ZZ too)

Answer (score 8):

That's because `this.move<<4` returns an int.

When Java finds [a shift operator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.19) it applies   [unary promotion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.1) to each operand; in this case, both operands are promoted to `int`, and so is the result. 
The behaviour is similar for other Java operators; see a related and instructive discussion, "[Varying behavior for possible loss of precision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2696812/varying-behavior-for-possible-loss-of-precision)".

Comment: The link was very useful for me but there is no example there about bitwise shifting. The explanation there is about compound assignment statement.

Answer (score 5):

The bitwise OR operands are subject to Binary Numeric Promotion. Here is how its' defined in JLS,

> 5.6.2 Binary Numeric Promotion
>
> When an operator applies binary
>   numeric promotion to a pair of
>   operands, each of which must denote a
>   value of a numeric type, the following
>   rules apply, in order, using widening
>   conversion (§5.1.2) to convert
>   operands as necessary:
>
> - If either operand is of type double,    the other is converted to
>     double.
> - Otherwise, if either operand is of    type float, the other is converted to 
>     float.
> - Otherwise, if either operand    is of type long, the other is
>     converted to long.
> - Otherwise, both operands are converted to type int.

As you can see, there is no byte type so all the bytes are promoted to int by default. You have to cast it back to byte to get rid of the warning,

```
this.move=(byte)((this.move<<4)|(Guy.moven.indexOf("left")&0xF));
```

Comment: Actually here a pair of Unary Numeric Promotions ocurr, not a binary see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/expressions.html#5121