# Incompatible types error Java between short and int. Unsure of cause

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, precision

In the following code I have an error 
"possible loss of precision
found   : int
required: short".
I understand what the error means but I'm just wondering why I'm getting it. Surely the function should return a type of short (I can't see how there *could* be any loss of precision, the code should return a 16 bit integer). Can anyone clear up for me why the following code seems to require the type int?

```
static short a() {
    short[] payload = {
            100, 200, 300,
            400, 500, 600,
            700, 800, 900, 1000
    };
    short offset = 2;
    return (payload[offset - 2] << 8 & 0xff00) + (payload[offset - 1] & 0xff);
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2696812/varying-behavior-for-possible-loss-of-precision and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2799084/possible-loss-of-precision-is-java-going-crazy-or-im-missing-something/2799122

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Java arithmetic operations on `short` always return `int`, partly to help prevent overflow, and partly to reflect the underlying JVM bytecode, which doesn't distinguish between arithmetic operations on `int`, `short`, or `byte`.  But basically, `(payload[offset - 2] << 8 & 0xff00)` is an `int`, and it wants you to cast it back down to a short.

Comment: I've even forgot about that :) I never really used shorts before.

Comment: @MarioDeSchaepmeester They can be quite useful in the summer.

Comment: What, so the mosquitos can byte my legs off? ;)