# += int and double conversion

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Varying behavior for possible loss of precision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2696812/varying-behavior-for-possible-loss-of-precision)

```
int testing = 0;
testing += 2.0
```

the above code compiles.

where as

```
int testing = 0;
testing = testing + 2.0;
```

this code doesn't compile. Any idea why?

Answer (score 8):

Compound assignment has a hidden cast in Java.

#### [JLS 15.26.2 Compound Assignment Operators](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.26.2):

> A compound assignment expression of the form *E1 op= E2* is equivalent to *E1 = (T)((E1) op (E2))*, where *T* is the type of *E1*, except that *E1* is evaluated only once.
>
> For example, the following code is correct:
>
> ```
> short x = 3;
> x += 4.6;
> ```
>
> and results in `x` having the value `7` because it is equivalent to:
>
> ```
> short x = 3;
> x = (short)(x + 4.6);
> ```

#### Related questions

- [Varying behavior for possible loss of precision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2696812/varying-behavior-for-possible-loss-of-precision)