# Why doesn't compound assignment in Java catch overflow problems?

Tags: java, integer-overflow, compound-assignment

To my shock, it turns out that the following code will compile without even warnings:

```
public void test()
{
    int value = 2000000000;
    long increment = 1000000000;
    value += increment;
}
```

Whereas this gives a compile-time error, as you would expect:

```
public void test()
{
    int value = 2000000000;
    long increment = 1000000000;
    value = value + increment;
}
```

I checked it up and indeed, the JLS (section 15.26.2) has this to say:

> A compound assignment expression of the form E1 op = E2 is equivalent to
>   E1 = (T) ((E1) op (E2)), where T is the type of E1, except that E1 is evaluated
>   only once.

This seems ridiculous to me.  Why did they feel the need to explicitly cast here?  It seems that automatic type conversion would have handled the widening anyway, and automatically narrowing like this is pretty much guaranteed to result in integer overflow.

Comment: Good question.  Never made much sense to me.  Maybe James Gosling will respond since he's a Googler now and should have lots of free time...

Comment: @squawknull - what makes you think that a Googler is going to waste his precious "one day a week" on pointless SO debates?  :-)

Comment: @Stephen C: That's my laugh of the day.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Here](http://aloshbennett.wordpress.com/2008/09/13/compound-assignment-operator-and-type-casting/) is one explanation:

> When you do an assignment (the first code snippet), java enforces type checking because the LHS and RHS may very well be independent of each other.
>
> But the compound-operator is more like
>   an incremental operator. The +=
>   modifies the value of the variable
>   involved, rather than assigning a new
>   value to the variable. When you modify
>   a byte, you expect a byte as the
>   result. To make life easier, java does
>   an implicit type conversion for
>   compound-operators because they are
>   modifiers.

Answer (score 2):

The compound assignment operators are specified by the JLS ([15.26.2](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.26.2)) as follows:

> *"A compound assignment expression of the form `E1 op= E2` is equivalent to*

```
      E1 = (T)((E1) op (E2))`,
```

> *where T is the type of E1, except that E1 is evaluated only once."*

In this case E1 is of type `int` E2 is of type `long`, and op is `+`.  So this is equivalent to:

```
value = (int)(value + increment);
```

The addition of an `int` and a `long` gives a `long` that is then cast back to an `int` before assignment.  That is all fine, hence no compilation error.

The difference between this and the simple assignment (i.e. `value = value + increment;`), is that the simple assignment doesn't have a typecast.

---

OK, so *why* did they define it this way?

I think that the reason is to make examples like this work:

```
    byte b = ...
    b += 1;
```

Without the typecast, `b += 1` would be a compilation error and you'd need to write it as:

```
    b += (byte) 1;
```

Comment: Don't you think that allowing it even for byte is dangerous though?  What if instead of adding 1, that code was adding 128?

Answer (score 1):

This link has analyzed the problem you have brought up.

[Varying behavior for possible loss of precision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2696812/varying-behavior-for-possible-loss-of-precision)

> To avoid unpleasant surprises, do not
>   use compound assignment operators on
>   variables of type byte, short, or
>   char. When using compound assignment
>   operators on variables of type int,
>   ensure that the expression on the
>   right-hand side is not of type long,
>   float, or double. When using compound
>   assignment operators on variables of
>   type float, ensure that the expression
>   on the right-hand side is not of type
>   double. These rules are sufficient to
>   prevent the compiler from generating
>   dangerous narrowing casts.