# Java breaks strong typing! Who can explain it?

Tags: java, strong-typing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Varying behavior for possible loss of precision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2696812/varying-behavior-for-possible-loss-of-precision)

I found an inconsistence in Java strong typing check at compile time.
Please look at the following code:

```
int sum = 0;
sum = 1; //is is OK
sum = 0.56786; //compile error because of precision loss, and strong typing
sum = sum + 2; //it is OK
sum += 2; //it is OK
sum = sum + 0.56787; //compile error again because of automatic conversion into double, and possible precision loss
sum += 0.56787; //this line is does the same thing as the previous line, but it does not give us a compile error, and javac does not complain about precision loss etc.
```

Can anyone explain it to me? Is it a known bug, or desired behavior?
C++ gives a warning, C# gives a compile error.

Does Java breaks strong typing?
You can replace += with -= or *= - everything is acceptable by a compiler.

Comment: weird is that you are storing float in int variable

Comment: @KarelFrajtak A decimal number without a modifier (like `d` or `f`) is a double, not a float. Besides, I think you might be missing the point..

Comment: Java clearly made a mistake here. They should have been more precise in when the silent cast is allowed. And the reason for the cast roots in another bad decision. The spec on integeral type operations is a stinky mess.

Comment: @irreputable: The rules for floating-point types are worse.  If both were allowed, which would be more worthy of a warning: `float f=1.0/10.0;` or `double d=1.0f/10.0f;`?  A good language should be able to define an `==` operator so it behaves as an equivalence relation in all cases which compile (the fact that `x==y` compiles and `y==z` compiles would not imply that `x==z` must compile, but if all three compile and two return true, the third should as well), but Java's fails in many regards.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This behaviour is defined by the language (and is therefore OK). From [the JLS](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.26.2):

> **15.26.2 Compound Assignment Operators**
>
> A compound assignment expression of the form E1 op= E2 is equivalent
>   to E1 = (T)((E1) op (E2)), where T is the type of E1, except that E1
>   is evaluated only once. For example, the following code is correct:
>
> ```
> short x = 3;
> x += 4.6;
> ```
>
> and results in x having the value 7 because it is equivalent to:
>
> ```
> short x = 3;
> x = (short)(x + 4.6);
> ```

Comment: This is something that is often over-looked, we tend to think += is just a shorter version to write, but it does have other implications. Good tip to remember.

Comment: it's not OK. java is wrong. there is no reason the example should compile.

Comment: @irreputable - well, that is something to take up with the language designer; the compiler conforms to the specification.

Comment: that's (the less important) part of the question.

Answer (score 5):

It compiles because the compiler is converting

```
sum += 0.56787;
```

to

```
sum = (int)(sum + 0.56787);
```

Comment: Can You provide a link to a document, that explains this behavior. I thought  that normal behavior is automatic conversion into a type with higher precision.

Comment: The cast is performed after the addition, not before. See the top answer.

Answer (score 3):

This has nothing to do with strong typing but only with different rules for implicit conversions.

You are looking at two different operators here. In the first case, you have the simple assignment operator "=" which does not allow assigning a `double` to an `int`. In the second case, you have the compound assignment operator "+=" which allows adding a `double` to an `int` by converting the `double` to an `int` first.

Comment: Yes, but this is very different to how things work in C++ or C#.

Comment: Sure, these are Java-specific rules from the JLS.

Comment: Eh? The choice of rules for implicit conversions, by definition, is all about strong vs. weak typing.

Comment: Yes, but this question is not about strong vs. weak typing. It's about recognizing that there are two different operators with two different sets of implicit conversions.