# Why does Java perform implicit type conversion from double to integer when using the "plus equals" operator?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Varying behavior for possible loss of precision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2696812/varying-behavior-for-possible-loss-of-precision)

Code Sample A

```
 public class Test {                                                         
     public static void main(String[] args) {
         int i = 0;
         i = i + 1.5;
     }
 }
```

Code Sample B

```
 public class Test {                                                         
     public static void main(String[] args) {
         int i = 0;
         i += 1.5;
     }
 }
```

Unsurprisingly, compiling A produces the error below. **Surprisingly**, compiling B produces no error and it appears to behave as if I inserted an explicit cast to integer before the double value 1.5.  Why in the world does this happen?  This goes against everything I thought I knew!

```
Test.java:6: possible

 loss of precision

    found   : double
    required: int
            i = i + 1.5;
                  ^
    1 error
```

Comment: @Dave is right on the disconcerting part.  Oh well, no language is perfect. :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**It is working as designed.** The compound operators add an implicit cast to the operation. Otherwise you have to use an explicit cast.

More info?

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26.2

Comment: +1 Good answer but here is a more direct link: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#5304

Comment: Fair enough about the link. Thanks!

Comment: Saying "that's how they intended it to work" is different from answering the question of why it works that way.  Can anyone give a justification for this decision?  On the surface, the silent cast seems error-prone in a language that requires explicit casting everywhere else.

Comment: @EricLindauer: I expect it works as it does because the arithmetic operators never give a result of any type smaller than `int` but Java wanted to allow `+=` to be usable on smaller types, and Java places a higher priority on making type conversion rules simple and "consistent", than on allowing things which make sense while disallowing things which are likely erroneous.

Answer (score 4):

According to the [Java language specification, section 15.26.2](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#5304):

A compound assignment expression of the form E1 op= E2 is equivalent to E1 = (T)((E1) op (E2)), where T is the type of E1, except that E1 is evaluated only once.
For example, the following code is correct:

```
short x = 3;
x += 4.6;
```

and results in x having the value 7 because it is equivalent to:

```
short x = 3;
x = (short)(x + 4.6);
```