# Strange typecast while doing variableOfTypeA+=variableOfTypeB

Tags: java, casting, type-conversion

I am using Java and new to it.

When I try

```
int integerValue = 100;
long longValue = 100;
integerValue = integerValue + longValue;
```

I get "Type mismatch: cannot convert from long to int".

But

```
integerValue+=longValue;
```

works fine, which means it is doing the cast for me :)

Is it something that "+=" provides inherently? Any specific reason for that?

Edit: Oops!! Too common question! :) I should have thoroughly searched first, my bad!!

Comment: Duplicate of  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8272635/why-does-java-perform-implicit-type-conversion-from-double-to-integer-when-using

Comment: possible duplicate of [Varying behavior for possible loss of precision](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2696812/varying-behavior-for-possible-loss-of-precision)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone!

All answers were good enough!

Better explanations and examples available at [stackoverflow.com/questions/8710619/java-operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8710619/java-operator/) :)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is behaving exactly as [section 15.26.2 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26.2) explains.

> A compound assignment expression of the form `E1 op= E2` is equivalent to `E1 = (T) ((E1) op (E2))`, where `T` is the type of `E1`, except that `E1` is evaluated only once.

Answer (score 2):

You have uncovered the Tweedledum puzzle from the [Java Puzzlers book](http://www.javapuzzlers.com/).
Basically the compound assignment performs type cast and regular one doesn't.  See [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26.2) for details.

Answer (score 1):

Using the operation assignment operators, there is an implicit cast.

```
int i = 10;
i *= 5.5;
// same as
i *= (int) (i * 5.5);
```

or even

```
char ch = '5';
ch /= 1.1; // ch = '0'
```

Answer (score 1):

That's correct. In your first example, you have to cast to `int`, because the result result of the left expression is a `long` value (only because `longValue` is `long`).

```
 integerValue = (long) (integerValue + longValue);  // this works
```

The `+=` operator does the (same) casting implicity.

Both behaviours are specified in the Java Language Specification.