# Java: why can this be compiled?

Tags: java

This is fail.

```
int i = 2;
i = i -Double.MIN_VALUE;
```

But this is past

```
int i = 2;
i -= Double.MIN_VALUE;
```

Why can it be compiled?

I am using JDK 8

Comment: There's an implicit cast when you use the `-=` operator, which makes the second snippet compile.

Comment: Have a look:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8272635/why-does-java-perform-implicit-type-conversion-from-double-to-integer-when-using