# Char arithmetic - difference between unary ++ and + 1

Tags: java

What is the difference between using the short forms and the long forms in Java? Look at the following code:

```
char myChar = 'p';
myChar += 2;
myChar++;
myChar = myChar + 2;        
System.out.println(myChar);
```

Line 2 and 3 work like expected. Line 4 gives the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
        Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to char
```

I thought line 2 and 4 are the same. But the seem to be not the same?

Comment: In case 1 and 2. there is an *implicit conversion* from int to char. If you look at the byte-code you will see `i2c` instruction. Case 3, you will have to explicitly convert it to char.

Comment: [Difference between a += 10 and a = a + 10 in java?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2081932/995714), [Java += operator](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8710619/995714)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For

`myChar += 2;`

From [JLS 15.26.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26.2):

> A compound assignment expression of the form E1 op= E2 is equivalent
>   to E1 = (T)((E1) op (E2)), where T is the type of E1, except that E1
>   is evaluated only once.

So, it is equivalent to:

`myChar = (char) (myChar + 2);`

As for

`myChar = myChar + 2;`

`myChar` is promoted to `int` and added to `2`. Now you are assigning this value which is an `int` to `char` which results in the error.

Answer (score 3):

In the unary forms it's implicit that the operand's type is unchanged.

In the binary form, the addition of the integer `2` causes the type of the whole expression `myChar + 2` to be promoted to `int`, causing the assignment back to the `char myChar` to fail.

Comment: So... `myChar = myChar + (char)2`?

Comment: By the quote from a now-deleted answer by @thegauravmahawar, `myChar += 2` is not equivalent to `myChar = myChar + 2`, but to `myChar = (char) (myChar + (char) 2))` ([source](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26.2)).

Comment: also - `myChar = myChar + (char)2` doesn't work - you get a "possible loss of precision" error.

Answer (score 0):

A compound assignment expression of the form `E1 op= E2` is equivalent to `E1 = (T)((E1) op (E2))`, where T is the type of E1, except that E1 is evaluated only once.

The statement `myChar+ = 2;` will be implictly converted into `myChar =(char) (myChar + 2);`

Comment: no, it won't - it'll be implicitly converted to `(char)(myChar + 2)` - not quite the same thing

Answer (score 0):

This is due to automatic promotion.

```
int+char will result to int
int+double will result to double
```

Now if you try to

```
int +char ---> store to char
int +double ---> store to int
```

this will cause an error.

---

but if you try

```
char c='a';
c++;
```

it is equal to

```
char c = 'a';
c = (char)(c+1);
```

instead if you use

```
char c = 'a';
c = c+2;//error
```

because it is

```
char + int ---> store to char(explained above)//error
```

hence for writing `c = c+2;`
use `c = (char)(c+2);`
now this works as follows.....

```
c+2; is basically (char + int) so the result is int(& not char)
```

when you do `(char)(c+2);` `the int value is converted to char`

---

**Note**

The limit of char in java is from 0 to 65535. 
So if the result of

```
(char)(char + int)---> store to char
```

overflows the value then you get unexpected output.

for example

```
char c  = (char)65535;//valid
c++; will result as c = 0 (not 65536) due to the limit of char.
```